# How can I use a parameter variable's literal value inside a Javascript function in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a form using React JS and I want some of the sections in the form to be dynamically added/removed using +/- button(s). I have created a custom Hook "inputs" which is a collection (object) of the data input from all the sections in the form. inputs contains an array for a section that I want to be dynamically added/removed. e.g., workInfos is one such section:

```
 const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({workInfos: [],
                                            educationInfos : [],
                                            basicInfo : {}, 
                                            skillInfo : {}});
```

I have created a button to add the workInfo section dynamically and assigned a function "handleDynamicAddition" to its onClick property:

```
<Button className = "button" variant="contained" color="secondary" style = {buttonStyle} onClick = {props.handleDynamicAddition()} >+</Button>
```

handleDynamicAddition function looks like:

```
const handleDynamicAddition = () => {
        setInputs((inputs) => ({...inputs, workInfos : [...inputs.workInfos, {}]}));
    }
```

This works fine as long as I use it for just one section.
I want to use the same function for all the sections that I want to add/remove dynamically, say, educationInfos.

For different buttons, I can pass the specific section that I want to add dynamically using that button, as a parameter to handleDynamicAddition but how do I use this parameter's actual value inside setInputs?

Comment: `onClick = {() => setInputs( your dynamic parameter here )}` if this is what you intent to do.
Inline function is not necessarily a bad practice as people oppose. I felt like it's too early to factor now based on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, you try something like this

Button:

```
<Button
    className="button"
    variant="contained"
    color="secondary"
    style={buttonStyle}
    name={/*one of the objects keys as a string, like: "workInfos", "educationInfos", etc.*/}
    onClick={handleDynamicAddition}
  >
    +
  </Button>
```

Handle:

```
const handleDynamicAddition = (evt) => {
  const {name} = evt.currentTarget;
  setInputs((inputs) => ({ 
    ...inputs, 
    [name]: [...inputs[name], {}] 
  }));
};
```

This pulls the "name" attribute from the clicked button and uses that to help assign "added sections" to the inputs object.

Kinda want to add this. If the form is pretty complicated, you're probably going to want to split things up. It's nice to have everything be "all in one place" but this sorta code should only really be used with primitive values like: `[name]: value` where value is a string or number. If you try to force this kind of thing to work with "objects inside of objects inside of arrays" it's going to become really unreadable compared to if you just broke things down and split them up.

Also, you might want to use a `useReducer` here, or even maybe look into Redux, instead of a `useState`. Depending on how complicated the application is going to get.